# Get most recent record, aggregated by 2 dates?

Tags: mysql, sql

Have a `UsersEntry` table

```
id | UID | RelationshipID | Value1 | ModDate | CreateDate
```

UID can be inserted multiple times in this table (once per RelationshipID). ModDate is null upon creation so could have the following

```
1 | 5 | 1  | 100 | null                | 2020-03-16 01:59:29
2 | 5 | 10 | 100 | 2021-03-01 01:59:29 | 2020-03-16 01:59:29
3 | 5 | 30 | 100 | 2021-03-16 01:59:29 | 2020-03-16 01:59:29
4 | 8 | 30 | 100 | null                | 2020-03-16 01:59:29
```

For user UID 5, I'd like to pull record ID 2. For UID 8, I'd like to pull record 4.

All I really care to return is `UserID` and `Value1` (the most recently modified Value1 per user.

Thanks!

Not sure why I'm getting downvotes... I've tried group by but the comparison for the  2 dates are throwing me off.

Comment: Go on. Try something

Comment: I have been. I tried group by, etc. But the 2 dates are throwing me off. @strawberry

Answer (score -1):

Window functions are a typical approach:

```
select ue.*
from (select ue.*,
             row_number() over (partition by UID order by modDate desc) as seqnum
      from UsersEntry ue
     ) ue
where seqnum = 1;
```